# Load data from csv into numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am trying to load data in a csv file (with delimiter ',') into a numpy array. Example of a line is: 81905.75578271,81906.6205052,50685.487931,.... (1000 columns).
I have this code but it seems to not be working properly as in the exit of the function the debugger cannot recognize the data, and when I call the xtrain.shape it returns 0:

```
def load_data(path):
    # return np.loadtxt(path,dtype=int,delimiter=',')
    file = open(path,'r')
    data = []
    for line in file:
        array_vals = line.split(",")
        array = []
        for val in array_vals:
            if not val:
                array.append(float(val))
        data.append(np.asarray(array))
    return np.asarray(data)

x_train =  load_data(path)
```

Comment: use pandas `read_csv` method.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you your required output.

```
import numpy as np
def load_data(path):
    return np.loadtxt(path,delimiter=',')
```

Comment: I actually tried before, but it didnt work. Ive just realized that there were some ',' at the end of some lines in the file -.-