# How to load such [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]..........]data into python from csv file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

Hi I have some date in the follwing format [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],.........] in a csv file.

Its a 3x100 array. Please suggest me how to load the data to numpy arrray and I also want to perform one hot encoding upon it.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with what you have tried.

Comment: its not possible to show data every time @Chris. its not a general programming question  that you want "minimal ,Complete and Verifiable example' its machine learning dude.

Comment: As apparent from the *answer*, MCVE applies here as well (and the question is *not* ML, BTW - it is simple data handling).

Comment: Seems a duplicate of: [Load data from csv into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831039/load-data-from-csv-into-numpy-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not shared the csv file correctly,
here is my best guess

first, read the data from file using simple file read operation
next use json module to convert it to list

```
import json
a= '[[1,11,1],[7,7,77],[5,6,7]]'
a = json.loads(a)
```

it will give you list of list 
as `[[1, 11, 1], [7, 7, 77], [5, 6, 7]]`

convert it to python dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
```

You can directly use pandas `Categorical` function to create one hot encoding ex

```
df['col2'] = pd.Categorical(df['col2'])
```